# Entity Framework with Database First model

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-data-services, ef-database-first

I am developing in ASP.NET MVC with EF 4.1 with Data Annotations. The client side validation is working as expected. But I have this doubt. For example when a required field (example: product name) , goes null from the client to server and if the entity model is throwing exception. How can I handle this case?

Some additional info is that, I consume the EF via WCF service layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be validating the model on the server side/controller too by calling model.isvalid, for more info on MVC server side validation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410404(v=vs.90).aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: That looks great. I thought of firing the Data Annotation validations by default without doing this manual validations

Comment: You could implement a custom action filter, which calls the isvalid on the model before, there's a nice little blog on it here: http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/automatic-modelstate-validation-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Just be cautious doing it this way as it might add some confusion.